# Нужно ли обособлять "при прочих равных условиях"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Зависит ли обособление этой фразы от места в предложении? Чем является в предложении?

Примеры:

Это, при прочих равных условиях, может быть благоприятным фактором для развития.

В различных странах результаты осуществления данной политики могут, при прочих равных условиях, стать ориентиром при формировании и реализации этого направления деятельности государства.

Тем самым они могут, при прочих равных условиях, получить благоприятную современную среду для инновационного развития.

Конечные цели конструктивной политики в их отношении могу при прочих равных условиях выступать и важными инструментами реализации государственной региональной политики.

И если общность негативных тенденций при прочих равных условиях может быть объяснена...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересный, но сложный вопрос. Я думаю, что примерно во всех случаях выражение "при прочих равных условиях" может факультативно выделяться знаками препинания (скобками, тире, запятыми). Нет оснований считать это выражение вводным, но авторы вполне могут видеть в нём поясняющую вставную конструкцию. С другой стороны, данное выражение не имеет ярко выраженных характеристик вставной конструкции и может быть прочитано в тесной связи с остальным предложением. Поэтому многие авторы его никак не выделяют. В добротной литературе можно найти самые различные примеры с выделением или без в совершенно равных условиях.